# Using image as a container?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible for me to remove the container div completely and turn the image into the container, retaining the width and height of the image but also keeping the styles of the container that is already in my stylesheet? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```css
.img_zoom_container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 45%;
}

.img_zoom_window {
  border: 2px solid #d4d4d4;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 0%;
  margin-left: -200px !important;
  transform: scale(0) translateY(-50%);
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transition: all ease .2s;
}

.img_zoom_container:hover .img_zoom_window {
  left: 170%;
  transform: scale(1) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="img_zoom_container">
  <img id="main_img_kit" class="prod_img mobile_hideb" height="300" width="300">
  <div id="img_main" class="img_zoom_window"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't you set the container background with the image?

Comment: You mean, adding elements inside an img like you would inside a div ? then no , not possible. for eg position relative, display flex etc. are useless on an image

Comment: @FelipeLanza yes I could but as of now the container is shifting some other elements on my page so I was wondering if possibly resizing the container to the size of the image would do the trick?

Comment: @MihaiT Okay that's what I thought, I wasn't completely sure. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Then you're probably better off changing the position property of either the div in question or the elements you claim to be shifting.

Answer (score 0):

As Felipe mentioned, if you are trying to display other elements on top of (within) the image, you could always set the image as the background of the container and simply put more containers within the outer container for your other divs.

Answer (score 0):

One method to have a background image push the parent containers width and height would be to use 2 images.

```
<div class='container'>
  <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/350x150' class='pusher' />
  <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/350x150' class='animator' />
</div>
```

They can be the same image just with one at 0 opacity and pointer events disabled. This approach is also easy to make responsive. I set up a demo for you here:

https://codepen.io/cidicles/pen/djMXeW

Hope it helps!